# js library for directed acyclic graphs with drag and drop support

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, directed-acyclic-graphs, directed-graph

I'm looking for a js graphing library that supports creating directed acyclic graphs using drag and drop. The UI would have a canvas with a list of elements that can be dragged onto the canvas to create a directed acyclic graph. Objects have labels and properties. Relationships between objects are depicted by the connections between them.

I've seen a number of great threads with thorough lists of js libraries but none of them seemed to be designed for building a drag and drop UI. They seem quite capable of rendering predesigned graphs.

Comment: - https://js.cytoscape.org/


- https://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/ui-extensions

Answer (score 0):

You can look at ([jgraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html)). And ([this](http://draw.io)) is one of their technology demonstration sites.